android data not showing package folder
I have stored the files into this Android/data path like /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/personalprojects.seakyluo.randommenu/files/RandomMenu/ExportedData/RandomMenu20240701_004823.zip
But in my windows and my cell phone, I couldn't find either the directory personalprojects.seakyluo.randommenu or the zip file. The zip file is definitely created because I can see the size of the app getting increased by 3gb.
What is wrong?

I have tried using a scanner to scan the zip file just created, but it doesn't help. And I couldn't access the this path /Android/data/personalprojects.seakyluo.randommenu directly.
public static void scanFile(Context context, String path) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[] { path },
            null, // mimeType
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.d("MediaScannerHelper", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.d("MediaScannerHelper", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
}

